# Eclipse and Android: cannot debug on Samsung Galaxy S2 because not detected

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, galaxy

I am just starting to learn on Android development. I use Ubuntu 11.10 and Eclipse. I have installed the needed plugins from android development, and I have also write yet some examples that compiles and run fine on the emulator.

But somethings as multitouch cannot be tested on the emulator, so I want to test them on my real Samsung Galaxy S2 device. The problem is that I have tried everything I have found on the web on this, but still have not been able to use it.

When I run ./adb devices, it does show none, although the device IS attached.

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I have modified /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules many times in different ways following instructions on the web, but none of them make a difference. Currently I have this line in it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}="6860", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Of course I tried restarting udev and adb services, even rebooting the whole system, but it did not work neither.

Any hint?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable USB Debugging on the device from the Settings -> Applications -> Development

Answer (score 3):

Try Samsung kies, it delivers suitable ADB driver:
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

With the right adb driver (from kies or elsewhere) it should work flawlessly

EDIT:
on linux: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

> If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules
>   file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you
>   want to use for development. In the rules file, each device
>   manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the
>   ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs,
>   below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux: Log in as root and
>   create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules. Use this format
>   to add each vendor to the file: SUBSYSTEM=="usb",
>   ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
>
> In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment
>   specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group
>   owns the device node. Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly
>   depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your
>   system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to
>   writing udev rules. Now execute: chmod a+r
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Comment: As told in the question, I am using Ubuntu, and Kies seems to be available only for Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try another USB cable

If you have a possibility, check if it works with another device

Localize your problem, make sure that it's something wrong with software (if it is)

Comment: Since the device is detected by the underlying OS, I do not think the cable is involved.

Comment: this is a Galaxy S2 specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command from a terminal

```
$ echo "0x04e8" >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

and restart adb using

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

check if the device is listed using `adb devices`

Comment: Have you enabled USB Debugging on the device from the Settings -> Applications -> Development ?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, you are fully right. I have found that problem a minute ago, and I was about to answer my question when I see your advice.

Comment: You may consider publishing your comment as an answer, so I can vote it as the choosen one.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue on Mac OS X with Eclipse. Simply putting the phone in 'debug' mode (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging) did not solve the issue. I have to do below in the command line to solve the issue.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```