# Eclipse Will Not Recognize Galaxy S 2 When Debugging

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse and Android: cannot debug on Samsung Galaxy S2 because not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300511/eclipse-and-android-cannot-debug-on-samsung-galaxy-s2-because-not-detected)

I am a java beginner. I am going through a book right now actually learning java and android programming. Anyways, to my problem. I am using eclipse to make a simple app and I want to transfer it to my galaxy s 2. I am ready to debug it and pick my device.... except its not there. I have installed Kies, the drivers, made sure its in USB debug mode but it will not recognize it. Any suggestions? This is not a duplicate! It is different because even though its in debugging mode, even though Ive reinstalled kies twice, even though Ive made sure the USB port or cord is not a problem it still does not work!

Answer (score 0):

as i know, it can't be used as testing device, when its connected to Kies.

you dont need Kies to debug, just make sure, that your PC sees your phone as a flash drive, than just turn USB debug mode on and run your app.

Comment: I have done this but eclipse still wont see it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you download http://www.sendspace.com/file/m6btv6. This worked for a Galaxy III. It is the USB driver only, not the entire Sansung Kies suite. It should let the ABD work fine.

Comment: This does not appear to work either. Any other possible solutions that anyone could give me would be awesome! Thanks for you guys help by the way!

Comment: Try a different MicroUSB cable, I have seen this affect the device showing up in Eclipse, even if the cable is working fine for everything else.

Comment: I dont think its a problem with the cord or the port because I have a my touch that I used and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable USB Debugging on the device from the `Settings -> Applications -> Development` . Most beginners are not aware of it.

Comment: I have done this and still does not work

Comment: I have Windows XP 64 bit. Would that make it not work for some reason?

Comment: Ive been doing a lot of resaerch and have heard a lot about this "Kill Server" seen here.  
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server

Comment: Does this code work? If so where do I put it and how do I execute it?